# Async code is not executed when app is in the background

Tags: android, react-native, android-jobscheduler

Using `react-native-background-fetch` I can force the `jobscheduler` to run with: `adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f <your.application.id> 999` when my app is running in the background.

This will execute all synchronous code but anything which is put on the call stack such as async, promises or setTimeout is not executed until the app is opened again. This all works fine on iOS.

```
BackgroundFetch.configure({
  minimumFetchInterval: 15, // minutes (15 is minimum allowed)
  stopOnTerminate: false,   // Android-only,
  startOnBoot: true         // Android-only
}, () => {
  console.log('Start background fetch') // Log happens

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('In timer!') // Log does not happen until app is opened
  }, 1000)
}, (error) => {
  console.error('[js] RNBackgroundFetch failed to start', error)
})
```

How can I run async code in the background on Android, am I missing some setup or configuration?